# populate a NSArray with data from a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm stuck! I can't get this to work.

This is what I plan to do:
Io have some data in .txt files that I eventually want to populate a NSArray with!
This is what I've done:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intsAndsStrings" ofType:@"txt"];
NSArray *objectsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:urlString];
NSLog(@"objectsArray is: %@", objectsArray);
```

The only output I get from the last line is;

```
    objectsArray is: (null)
```

The objects in the txtFile is separated with comma(,).

Please help me!

Comment: Your question is really about how to load a CSV file into an array. I suggest you do some searching on parsing CSV files. Depending on the data in the file, it's a lot more work that is seems at first. You may need to deal with values that contain commas or newlines.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted requires that the file be a plist type file with `array` as it's root element. If your `txt` file is just a plain old text file and you want each line of text to be put in the array then you need a whole different approach.

One option is to load the text file into an `NSString` variable then split the string into an array using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` passing in the `newlineCharacterSet`.

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intsAndsStrings" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *rawText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:urlString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *objectsArray = [rawText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Real code will properly deal with errors.

Edit: I just noticed that you state that the text file is a CSV file. This takes a bit more processing. Does the CSV file have more than one line? How should each value from each line be stored?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a million! you really helped me. There is another problem: The txt-file look like this: 1, @"one", 2, @"two", 3, @"four", 5, @"five", 6, @"six", 7, @"seven", 8, @"eight", 9, @"nine", 10, @"ten", nil I search for the int but uses the string.

Comment: Why are the text values setup to look like `NSString` literals? You should not have the `@` symbol or the quotes in the CSV file. You should only put the value in quotes if the value contains a comma. Also, why have `nil` at the end of the line in the text file?

Comment: And it seams the array isn't fit for holding ints and strings. What should I do?

Comment: @JohnWilund You should update your question with this additional information about the contents of the file. You should also update your question with your goal. What objects do you want to end up with in the array? Are you sure you want an array? Maybe a dictionary would be better. It seems you have a set of numbers that map to a string. If I was doing this I would get replace this comma separated text file with a plist file containing all of the keys and values. Then your code would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `initWithContentsOfFile:`, your file has to be in a Property List format, not a comma-separated format.  Check out the Property List Programming Guide.

Comment: John doesn't have a plist file; he has a CSV file. What should he do, then?

Comment: You should use a library like CHCSV Parser ... https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Answer (score 1):

As I see from the extension you're using, that's probably not a plist file.

You should use a plist file that contains an array, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>hello</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: John doesn't have a plist file; he has a CSV file. What should he do, then?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHCSVParser`. give it a path to a your file, and it'll give you back a whole bunch of NSStrings.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"csv"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (rows == nil) {
  //something went wrong; log the error and exit
  NSLog(@"error parsing file: %@", error);
  return;
}
```

At this point, rows is an array. Each element in rows is itself an array representing a single row in the CSV file. And each element of that array is an NSString.